# creating html with perl

Tags: javascript, html, perl

```
<header>
<script type="text/javascript">
function hideit()
{

var x1 = document.getElementsByTagName("ol").item(0);
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("ol");
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
  x[i].style.display="none";
}
function showit()
{
var x1 = document.getElementsByTagName("ol").item(0);

var x=document.getElementsByTagName("ol");
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
 x[i].style.display="";
}
</script><header>
<body>
foreach $key (keys %{$stats_data{$out}})  {

    print $indexfd ("<input onclick=\"showit()\" type=\"button\" id=\"<?perl echo     $key; ?>\" value=\"showit\"><br><input onclick=\"hideit()\" type=\"button\" id=\"<?perl   echo $key; ?>\" value=\"hideit\"><br><b><ol id=$key>$stats_data{$out}{$key}<ol id=$key>  </b><br>");
        }</body>
```

I am creating an html document with perl. I wrote an event mouseover and mouseout to happen for every perl variable  (over a loop). But looks like the event controls all the variables at the same time. How do I write the event only once but enable it to individually be applied for each item: this is what I have currently

but this html when displayed, does not let me control the event separately for each `$key`.

Even though the buttons do get created for each $key, clicking on one, controls the `$stats_data{$out}{$key}` of all.

I even tried passing the id to the show/hide script, but no luck.

Comment: It's a bit early in the morning, but I don't understand your code. Are you embedding perl code into a regular html file? Have you examined the result to make sure it looks like valid html and javascript?

Comment: I am trying to display my simulation results in a clean way and therefore creating a html document. Since the results are spread out in different directories in the form of different types of files. It involves parsing information from files etc. so I am writing a perl script to parse those information from files and create an html. I am printing information for each image in a loop.

Answer (score 7):

Your code looks like you are trying to mix Perl with HTML in a way you would use PHP. **This does not work in Perl.**

I tried fixing your Perl code first. This will print to your filehandle (which I omitted), but will not not give you the working JavaScript code. I did not change that since I did not understand what you want to do. More on that later.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
# open of $indexfd filehandle goes here..

# print head of HTML page
print $indexfd <<HTML
<html>
  <header>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function hideit() {
      var x1 = document.getElementsByTagName("ol").item(0);
      var x = document.getElementsByTagName("ol");
      for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
        x[i].style.display="none";
    }
    function showit() {
      var x1 = document.getElementsByTagName("ol").item(0);
      var x=document.getElementsByTagName("ol");
      for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
       x[i].style.display="";
    }
    </script>
  </header>
  <body>
HTML
;

# If I see this correctly, %stats_data looks like this:
my %stats_data = (
  'out1' => {
    'key1' => 'val1',
    'key2' => 'val2',
  },
  'out2' => {
    'key1' => 'val1',
    'key2' => 'val2',
  },
);
my $out = 'out1'; # you need the $out from somewhere
# print buttons for each data thingy - you'll want to sort them probably
foreach my $key (sort keys %{$stats_data{$out}})  {
  print $indexfd 
    qq~<input onclick="showit()" type="button" id="$key" value="showit"><br />~,
    qq~<input onclick="hideit()" type="button" id="$key" value="hideit"><br/>~,
    # Because $stats_data{$out} is a hash ref you need the -> operator here
    qq~<ol id="$key"><li><b>$stats_data{$out}->{$key}</b></li></ol><br/>~;
}

print $indexfd qq~<p>more html...</p></body></html>~;
```

So there are a few things worth mentioning.

```
    print $indexfd ("<input onclick=\"showit()\" type=\"button\" id=\"<?perl echo     $key; ?>\" value=\"showit\"><br><input onclick=\"hideit()\" type=\"button\" id=\"<?perl   echo $key; ?>\" value=\"hideit\"><br><b><ol id=$key>$stats_data{$out}{$key}<ol id=$key>  </b><br>");
```

In this rather long line of code you used `<?perl echo $key; ?>` which looks like php and doesn't work. You also used `<ol id=$key>` which works because you used double-quotes `"..."`. Perl substitutes the variables inside the "-delimited string for their values. You don't need that php-like stuff. In order to save yourself the effort of escaping all the double quotes in the HTML code you can use the `qq`-Operator. See [perlop](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlop#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators) for more infos.

I explained about the `%stats_data` data structure in my comments.

For printing the large chunk of HTML, I used [HERE docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlop#EOF).

Let's talk about your JavaScript now.

> Even though the buttons do get created for each `$key`, clicking on one, controls the `$stats_data{$out}{$key}` of all.

This is because of the way you designed your `hideit()` and `showit()` functions. I'm not really ceratin what you want to achieve. If you look at my `%stats_data` you'll see that there are several keys in 'out1'. That lets the foreach-loop print a set of buttons for each of those keys. The buttons both have the same key as their id, as does the ol. That is not correct. An [id-attribute has to be unique](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id).

Furthermore, there were some basic issues in your html which I took the liberty to fix as well. If you open an `<ol id="foo">` container, you need to close it like `</ol>`. Since `<ol>` is a block-level element, you shouldn't put the inline element `<b>` outside it, but rather inside the ol's `<li>` elements (which I omitted). It would be better yet to just assign css ``style="font-weight: bold" to the li items or better yet give them classes.

I'll take one last guess at what you were trying to do with the JavaScript. If you have several paragraphs of text and you want to hide them with buttons, you could do that like my untested code here.

Javascript:

```
function toggle(id) {
  if (document.getElementById(id).style.display == 'block' ) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div>
  <input type="button" name="toggle1" id="toggle1" onclick="toggle('p1')" />
  <p id="p1">Lorem ipsum dolor set ... foo a lot of text 1.</p>
  <input type="button" name="toggle2" id="toggle2" onclick="toggle('p2')" />
  <p id="p2">Lorem ipsum dolor set ... foo a lot of text 2.</p>
</div>
```

In this case, the function checks whether the paragraph is shown or not. The display-value needs to be set to 'none' or 'block', because the p-element is a block-level element.

Please try to post more specific information about the data you use with your script if you need any more help.

**EDIT:**
In the following code I changed the JS functions to both take an id (the key) as a parameter. They only show or hide the lists associated with this key. I changed the button's ids so they're not the same. I also added a div around each pair of buttons and list to make it clearer what belongs where.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
# open of $indexfd filehandle goes here..
my $indexfd;

# print head of HTML page
print $indexfd <<HTML
<html>
  <header>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function hideit(key) {
      document.getElementById(key).style.display = "none";
    }
    function showit(key) {
      document.getElementById(key).style.display = "";
    }
    </script>
  </header>
  <body>
HTML
;

# If I see this correctly, %stats_data looks like this:
my %stats_data = (
  'out1' => {
    'key1' => 'val1',
    'key2' => 'val2',
  },
  'out2' => {
    'key1' => 'val1',
    'key2' => 'val2',
  },
);
my $out = 'out1'; # you need the $out from somewhere

foreach my $key (sort keys %{$stats_data{$out}})  {
  print $indexfd 
    qq~<div id="div_$key">\n~, # Add a div around the $key-elements
    qq~<input onclick="showit('$key')" type="button" id="btn_show_$key" value="showit">\n~,
    qq~<input onclick="hideit('$key')" type="button" id="btn_show_$key" value="hideit"><br/>\n~,
    qq~<ol id="$key"><li><b>$stats_data{$out}->{$key}</b></li></ol>\n~,
    qq~</div>\n~;
}

print $indexfd qq~<p>more html...</p></body></html>~;
```

Comment: Thanks so much for all the detailed answer. I actually posted a snapshot of my complete perl script so things looked a little bit odd. And I am sorry that you had to spend time correcting that. I do get output in the html. You are right that each out1 has several keys. I would like to print each key of each out1, each key having a expand contract menu display its $stats_data{$out}->{$key}. Your example above, how do I write that in a loop over out1 and $key?

Comment: Btw, I see you mentioned that the buttons getting created have the same key as their id. But that is not true. Since, the div tags are written inside a for loop on $key. Since I am passing the div tag id as $key and do this.id, shouldnt a separate control be created for each button per $key?

Comment: My question is for below lines in the script (the ones you wrote), how come even though buttons get created for each key, i cannot control the stats_data individually to show and hide for each key? what to do to control the two show hide for each key independently?foreach my $key (sort keys %{$stats_data{$out}})  {
  print $indexfd 
    qq~<input onclick="showit()" type="button" id="$key" value="showit"><br />~,
    qq~<ol id="$key"><li><b>$stats_data{$out}->{$key}</b></li></ol><br/>~;
}

Comment: +1, though I personally prefer using TT, like brian d foy suggests.

Comment: @torauser1354951 re keys: Both buttons and the ol had the same id (``$key``) in your code. That's not ok, ids are unique. I don't see divs in your code. Don't understand what you mean, sorry. Re 3rd comment: try to change it to resemble my html/js example and change it to two seperate functions. Put the id not on the button but the thing you want to hide. Pass the id as arg. Please post a part of your $stats_data (edit your question). You can replace the actual data with fake values if you're uncomfortable with what it says, but leave the structure. Maybe that way I'll understand your meaning.

Comment: I changed IDS of the buttons and ol to 3 unique values. Still see that when the html is created , one pair of button is controlling the $stats_data{$out}->{$key} of both keys. Since I am writing this in a for loop, it would be just one function write. How do I basically make several pair of buttons (one per $key) controll the expansion and contraction of the text under the corresponding $key independently?

Comment: this is how the data struct looks like ..i am using your example.

Comment: my %stats_data = (
  'out1' => {
    'key1' => 'val1',
    'key2' => 'val2',
  },
  'out2' => {
    'key1' => 'val1',
    'key2' => 'val2',
  },
);

Comment: @torauser1354951: see my changes. Is that what you want it to do? Can you please post the code you have now. You can edit your original question.

Comment: Yes. I am now running your example code and I see the same problem:

Comment: I have posted the code in the code block you wrote. I am repeating my qs again: how come i cannot control the text for each $key to expand and control with its own button independently.thanks

Comment: thanks simbabque. I found a solution for my last qs.Replaced $key by $j(=$.$key) for each of the tags

Comment: one more, how do I make the text be hidden by default when the page loads, i,e., all the vals

Comment: @torauser1354951: just add ``style="display: none"`` to all the containers you want hidden. Don't forget to display show-buttons though. ;)

Comment: @torauser1354951 at the top of the anwser, below the votes. See [the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) on how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want one of Perl's templating modules, such as [Template Toolkit](https://www.metacpan.org/module/Template). It allows you to embed Perl snippets inside larger documents then process them such that the Perl parts fill in whatever you need.

Here's an example from one of my websites. It uses wrapper files to include the top and bottom portions, and reads an XML file to get the data to fill in the middle:

```
[% 
        title   = "The Perl Review" 
        xml     = "raw/xml/tpr_issues.xml"
        sidebar = 1
%]

[% PROCESS top %]

<table class="content-table">
<tr>
        <td colspan class="2">  

<h2>Next issue: April 15</h2>

[% PERL %]

use XML::Twig;

my $twig = XML::Twig->new;   

$twig->parsefile( $stash->get( 'xml' ) ); 

my $root = $twig->root;

my $latest_issue = $root->first_child( 'release' );

my( $volume, $issue, $year, $season ) = 
        map { eval {$latest_issue->first_child( $_ )->text } }
                qw( volume issue year season );

my $articles = $latest_issue->first_child( 'articles' );

print <<"TEMPLATE";
        <A class="cover-link" href="/Subscribers/ThePerlReview-v${volume}i${issue}.pdf"><img 
                class="cover-image-medium" height="396" width="306" 
                src="/Images/covers/v${volume}i${issue}-cover-medium.png" /></a>
        </td>
        <td class="article-cell">
        <h2 id="issue-header">Issue $volume.$issue, $season $year</h2>

TEMPLATE

foreach my $article ( $articles->children( ) )
        {
        my @children = map { $_->tag } $article->children;

        my %hash = 
                map { 
                        $article->first_child( $_ )->tag,
                        $article->first_child( $_ )->text
                        } 
                map { $_->tag } $article->children;

        print qq|\t<p class="article-title"><span class="article-title">$hash{title}</span>|;
        print qq| (<a href="$hash{sample_page}">sample</a>)| if $hash{sample_page};
        print "<br />\n";
        print qq|\t\t<span class="article-author">$hash{author}</span></p>\n|;          
        }

[% END %]

[% PROCESS issue_note %]

        </td>
</tr>

</table>


[% PROCESS footer %]
```

Comment: I am trying to display my simulation results in a cleaner way and therefore creating a html document. Since the results are spread out in different directories and involves parsing information from files etc. I am writing a perl script to parse information from files and create an html. Do you still recommend me using the template? thanks

Comment: Yes, I almost always recommend using templates to create this sort of output.