# want to show or hide section of html page when it loads be default based on text box check option on top of the page

Tags: javascript, html

I have an html where I have bunch of text controlled by a show hide button, (say this code snippet is para). Now I would like to add additional layer of control on top of that. I would like to have a text box on top of the html page when it loads to have a option to hide or show para by default based on check uncheck of the text box.

Here is my code para

```
print $indexfd
qq~<div id="div_$var3">\n~, # Add a div around the $key-elements
qq~<input onclick="showit('$var3')" type="button" id="btn_show_$var3" value="showit">\n~,
qq~<input onclick="hideit('$var3')" type="button" id="btn_show_$var3" value="hideit"><br/>\n~,
qq~<ol id="$var3" style="display: none"><li><b>$var3->{name} \: $var3->{value}</b></li></ol>\n~,
qq~</div>\n~;
```

Comment: Also, this is quite similar to your [last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10307755/creating-html-with-perl) where you have still not accepted an answer. Please do that if you want other people to [help you](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).

Answer (score 1):

This isn't something Perl can do for you. You will need to do it in JavaScript. Have a look at the [jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery) lib's function [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/). That should do what you want. Add your paragraph and add some sort of button or whatever. Then add a `click`-handler to that button to `toggle` the paragraph.

Here's an excerpt from the documentation:

> We can animate any element, such as a simple image:
>
> ```
> <div id="clickme">
>   Click here
> </div>
> <img id="book" src="book.png" alt="" width="100" height="123" />
> ```
>
> We will cause .toggle() to be called when another element is clicked:
>
> ```
> $('#clickme').click(function() {
>   $('#book').toggle('slow', function() {
>     // Animation complete.
>   });
> });
> ```

Don't forget to [load the jQuery files](http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works) in the `<head>` section of your HTML document.

Comment: thanks.i will try this out and let you know..but i still couldn't figure out how to accept an answer.